# Can $x\pi$ be rational?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When I was solving a math test, I came across this problem -

> Let $x$ be an irrational number. What type of number is $x\pi$?
>
> a) Rational only
>
> b) Irrational only
>
> c) Could be rational or irrational

I was surprised to see that the answer was option **c**.

Can anyone tell me for what value of $x$ is $x\pi$ rational? Note that $x$ is a irrational number.

Comment: $1/\pi \cdot \pi$ and $\sqrt 2/ \pi \cdot \pi$ should resolve it for you.

Comment: To add on to this, what if it was given that $x$ was an irrational but NOT transcendental number? The reason so far for $\pi x$ being possibly rational is by constructing the specific example $\frac{k}{\pi}$ where $ k \in \mathbb{Q}$, but what if we remove this possibility?

Comment: if $x$ is algabraic and irrational (hence non-zero) then $\pi x$ is going to be trascendental so the answer would be $b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is $c$

It can be irrational as $\pi\sqrt 2$ is the product of a trascendental number and a non-zero algebraic number, hence trascendental and therefore irrational.

It can be rational as $\pi\cdot\frac{1}{\pi}=1$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\frac{1}{\pi}$ then they multiply to give $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=1/\pi$. It can't be rational, as then $\pi$ would be as well.  Still, their product is equal to $1$.

Comment: @SalmonKiller, it seems right to me. $\frac1\pi\notin\mathbb Q$ and $\frac1\pi\cdot\pi=1\in\mathbb Q$. What's the matter?